# How to call WCF service from javascript in .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, wcf

I add in my project WCF service (ProductService.svc in forder Services):

```
using System; 
using System.Linq;  
using System.Runtime.Serialization; 
using System.ServiceModel; 
using System.ServiceModel.Activation; 
using System.ServiceModel.Web; 
using System.Web.Services; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 

namespace Application.Services {
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode
= AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public class ProductService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [OperationContract]
        public static string GetMainGridProductHtml()
        {
            return "Helo World :)";
        }
    } 
 }
```

And try to call service from javascript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Application.Services.ProductService.GetMainGridProductHtml(ResultLoadTableMainGridHtml, ErrorLoadTableMainGridHtml);

function ResultLoadTableMainGridHtml(html) {
    debugger;
    alert("Ok");
}

function ErrorLoadTableMainGridHtml() {
    debugger;
    alert("Error");
}

function NewAddBtn() {
    debugger;
    alert("Yuppi");
}
</script>
```

It won't work: Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Application' is undefined
How can I manage this?

Comment: do you have a `asp:ScriptManager` with a `asp:ServiceReference` on the page?

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSON to achieve this in Javascript. 
Here is an example http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

i tried code similar to yours, and i think that
since you are using an empty namespace in

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
```

the javascript generated for the proxy is accessible using

```
ProductService.GetMainGridProductHtml
```

directly, and without the namespace `Application.Services`

EDIT: code sample:

in the `svc` file:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
Service="Application.Services.ProductService" 
Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"
CodeBehind="ProductService.svc.cs" %> // your cs file name may be different
```

in your aspx page you should have the script manager and reference 
(change the reference to your service ):

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Services>
                <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service1.svc" />
            </Services>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
```

in your web.config , when you added the WCF enabled WCF service, VS2010 adds the servcie model settings for WCF and AJAX:
your class names and namespaces are probably different, this was created on my machine:

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebApplication1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior">
              <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
          multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <services>
          <service name="WebApplication1.Service1">
            <endpoint address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="WebApplication1.Service1AspNetAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WebApplication1.Service1" />
          </service>
        </services>
      </system.serviceModel>
```

with all this in place you should be able to call the service on the client side
usign `ProductService.GetMainGridProductHtml()`.
(you may also see it in the debugger watch window, as you expected)

to make sure you get the javascript genereted correctly, browse to the url of the service + /jsdebug
i.e. http://localhost:3953/Service1.svc/jsdebug

Comment: in the `.svc` file do you have a `Factory` directive?

Comment: Loks like this: <%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Application.Services.ProductService" CodeBehind="ProductService.svc.cs" %>
 But when I try to view Watch, it doesn't see my servise and namespace at all.

Comment: try adding this after the `Service="..." ` : `Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory"`

Comment: I try but error in javascript manager. Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Services' is undefined...or 'Application' is undefined when I typed Application.Services

Comment: dont use `Application` or  `Services`. just use the `ProductService` directly.

Comment: But in javascript when I typed ProductService it looks like I try to run some function and obviously it appears error Object expected. In this scenario I need to type the way to service but when I work in javascript I cant use namespace, I tra to view it in Watch but in simply undefined. Why?

Comment: Here Link:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wcfinjavascript.aspx I try to Using Ajax-Enable WCF Service item template

Comment: its most likely becasue the client side javascript was not created properly for you by the factory. i`ll update my answer to include a sample of all the parts you need.

Comment: Web.config look like everything normal but it don't work. Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Services' (the forder where services locates) is undefined appears, when I type simply NameOfService.MethodOfService() - undefined NameOfService

Comment: i just noticed (very late) that the method `GetMainGridProductHtml` is static, which doesnt go very well with the `ServiceContract` attribute. can you make it an instance method ?

Comment: Ok) I find solution. 1) The are no correct code writing problem, ScriptManager works after javascript file was worded. 2) Like you sad, service method must be not static. I run not static method after DOM was formed. Method runs when user press on button, so when I need some method start to work by itself I will managed this with jQuery(document).ready(function(){...});   in javascript)))

Comment: and ScriptManager look like this: <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> 
            <Scripts>
                 <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Java.js" />
            </Scripts> 
            <Services>
                 <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Service.svc" />
             </Services>
    </asp:ScriptManager>